# How to move multiple elements to the beggining of the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a function that takes an array and string as arguments. The task is to chceck if the string occurs within the function and if does move to the first place of the array.

```
function moveToFirstPlace(['pizza', 'Pasta', 'Burger', 'PiZZa', 'pizzA'],'pizza')
```

in this example all pizzas have to be moved to the beggining of the array regardless of upper or lower letters.

Comment: please add your function.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the array and check the value and move this values to top.

```js
function moveToFirstPlace(array, value) {
    return array.sort((a, b) => (b.toLowerCase() === value) - (a.toLowerCase() === value));
}

console.log(moveToFirstPlace(['pizza', 'Pasta', 'Burger', 'PiZZa', 'pizzA'],'pizza'));
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to apply `filter` to your array, once to identify the matches, and once for the non-matches. Then just concatenate both results:

```js
function moveToFirstPlace(arr, str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    const matches = arr.filter(elem => elem.toLowerCase() === str);
    const misses = arr.filter(elem => elem.toLowerCase() !== str);
    return matches.concat(misses);
}

var arr = moveToFirstPlace(['pizza', 'Pasta', 'Burger', 'PiZZa', 'pizzA'],'pizza');

console.log(arr);
```

This will maintain the original order of matching elements. Note that it does not mutate the original array, but returns a new array as result.

You could also use a more functional approach with `reduce`:

```js
function moveToFirstPlace(arr, str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    return arr.reduce((acc, elem) => (acc[+(elem.toLowerCase() === str)].push(elem), acc), [[], []])
              .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b));
}

var arr = moveToFirstPlace(['pizza', 'Pasta', 'Burger', 'PiZZa', 'pizzA'],'pizza');

console.log(arr);
```

Both solutions have a linear time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `push` and `unshift` along with `toLowerCase()` to build a new array.

```js
function moveToFirstPlace(items, key) {
  let result = []
  items.forEach(itm => {
    itm.toLowerCase() == key.toLowerCase() ? result.unshift(itm) : result.push(itm)
  })
  return result
}

console.log(moveToFirstPlace(['pizza', 'Pasta', 'Burger', 'PiZZa', 'pizzA'], 'pizza'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If efficiency is important, you can do this in-place with one `O(n)` pass (not counting `toLowerCase`) by running indexes from each end of the array and swapping when the right index finds pizza and the left finds non-pizza:

```js
function moveToFirstPlace(arr, key){
  let i = 0, j = arr.length -1
  while (i < j){
    while(!arr[j].toLowerCase().includes(key)) j--;
    while(arr[i].toLowerCase().includes(key)) i++;
    if (i < j)
        [arr[j], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[j]];
    i++;
    j--;
  }
}
let arr = ['pizza', 'Pasta', 'Burger', 'PiZZa', 'pizzA']
moveToFirstPlace(arr,'pizza')
console.log(arr)
```